# MP3 sound files embedded with media9 cannot be played using ezpdf reader on android

Tags: media9

I created a PDF with MP3 files embedded following an example of `media9`:

```
\includemedia[
  addresource=sample.mp3,
  transparent,
  flashvars={
    source=sample.mp3
   &autoPlay=true
  },
]{\includegraphics[height=1.44ex]{speaker.png}}{APlayer.swf}
```

The audio file can be played with Adobe reader on windows perfectly, but not with ezpdf reader on an android device. When I created an PDF embedded with the same mp3 file using Adobe Acrobat 11, it works with ezpdf reader. I am using Tex Live 2017 with media9 v.0.79 installed.
I have found this from previous questions,
"ezPDF Reader was reported to playback video and sound files on tablets and phones with Android or iOS. Version 0.11 of media9 is required to make things work."
Does it only work with meidia9 Version 0.11?

Answer (score 4):

In order to play in ezPDF Reader, it seems to be necessary to embed the media file with option `playbutton=none` as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  addresource=bird.mp3,
  transparent,
  playbutton=none,
  flashvars={
    source=bird.mp3
   &autoPlay=true
  }
]{\fbox{\phantom{\rule{3in}{0.4in}}}}{APlayer.swf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure why, using this option `playbutton=none` does not help. Still my ezPDF reader v2.7.0.1 does not play the embedded MP3 file in a PDF where as the Adobe Acrobat Reader seems to do (it asks that I need flash support in my Windows computer and hence I assume it would work with flash support, but nothing happens with ezPDF).

Comment: @Narayanan ezPDF tries to read the embedded media file without Flash, as Flash is not available on mobile platforms (and will phase out on desktop OS too, by end of 2020). Do you have a sample PDF with audio that works in ezPDF? You could upload it on the media9 bug-tracker on GitLab, such that I could take a look: https://gitlab.com/agrahn/media9/issues Unfortunately, I don't have ezPDF available myself for testing.